# read value from a JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, symfony

how can I read values from a JSON in PHP? I need username, password and values from mandant-> name and abbr

thanks

[image: data]

Comment: try with `json_decode()` function ;) http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. This is my solution:

```
   $json = $request->getContent();
   $arrayJson = json_decode($json, true);
   $user = $arrayJson['user'];
   $password = $arrayJson['password'];
   $mandant = $arrayJson['mandant'];
   $mandantName = $mandant('name');
   $mandantAbbr = $mandant('abbr');
```